# HDMI Laptop to TV - Speakers cracking and popping when displaying video, but only listening to audio is fine

Tags: laptop, audio, hdmi, tv, hdtv

I'll start off by saying that I've had a few issues in getting the audio to go from the laptop to the TV but after uninstalling and re-installing the drivers a few times I got that to work. Even now though, every time I want to stream to the TV using the HDMI cable, I have to disable and re-enable the High Definition Audio Device (HDMI) Driver. So I don't know if this could be a part of the problem.

So I initially thought that the cracking and popping could be caused because I was streaming video, but this happens when I watch DVDs and when my videos are fully loaded still. So during my testing, I had youtube open and I opened a new tab to find out some information and the cracking / popping stopped while the audio still came through. I switched back to the youtube tab and the cracking / popping immediately returned.

So whenever the video is being displayed there is a popping / crackling noise. But if audio is just being played, there is no popping / crackling. Is the problem my TV, my laptop, or my HDMI cable? And how can I fix it?

My laptop specs are these:

```
HP Pavilion dv4-1431us
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6500 @ 2.10GHz 2.10GHz
4.00 GB RAM
32-Bit
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI carries both audio and video, so I hope you have not connected anything to the audio output.
It might be useful if you described exactly the connection to the TV.

Otherwise, things you could try:

1. Turn TV off and on when crackling starts (sometimes this helps)
2. Try using same laptop but with another TV
3. Try using same TV but with another laptop
4. Try using another HDMI cable (or another HDMI input on the TV)
5. Update firmware of TV and computer (BIOS)
6. Fully patch the computer (Windows Update including optional updates)
7. Download audio/video drivers from the manufacturer's website
8. Contact HP Support

Comment: The only cord I have plugged into the TV is the HDMI cord leading to the laptop. From your list, this is what I've tried so far. 1: Didn't solve it. 3 + 4: Xbox with same HDMI cord - doesn't have popping. 5: Both up to date already. 6: I'll check the optional updates tonight. 7: Have downloaded audio driver. So the problem is definitely with the laptop. It's an interesting idea to re-install the video driver, I'll do that tonight. I thought also that maybe my laptop is too slow to process a HD video and sound at the same time? What kind of processing speeds do I need to handle that?

Comment: I re-installed the video drivers with no luck. I feel that contacting HP Support they will just give me the 7 other suggestions on your list. Is there anything else?

Comment: The HP article [Overview of HDMI and DVI Connections for PCs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01409647&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=3983291) describes 3 types of HDMI cables, so I wonder which one is yours. In view of all these subtleties and the fact that the laptop automatically behaves differently for each cable type, contacting HP Support may not be as useless as it seems.